# How Can I debug R8 during compilation?

Tags: android, android-r8, android-d8

Is there any way to debug R8 during compilation of an Android project ?

I have a really weird error and the casual fix won't help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have the R8 project checked out (from https://r8.googlesource.com/r8) and is using IntelliJ as the debugger, this is a way to debug Gradle building an Android Studio project.

First build r8:

```
tools/gradle.py r8
```

The `r8.jar` is built in `build/libs` and should then be referenced in the main `build.gradle` file (in the `buildscript.repositories` section) like this:

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath files($PATH_TO_R8_JAR)  // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-rc03'
     }
}
```

To debug a command line Gradle run pass the options `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true` and `--no-daemon` when invoking Gradle, E.g. for a release build of an Android Studio project:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon
```

The gradle command will wait for the debugger to attach. In IntelliJ create a standard remote debugging configuration and attach. The gradle command will continue and breakpoints in the R8 code will be hit.

NOTE: That for a range of the 3.5.0 aplha releases adding `r8.jar` to `build.gradle` can cause issues for Kotlin projects (see [Issue 129240946](https://issuetracker.google.com/129240946)).

Answer (score 2):

For the `R8` shrinker, can add the `-verbose` switch into the `proguard.cfg` file. there's an option:

```
--pg-conf proguard.cfg
```

It's [build.gradle](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/r8/+/oreo-mr1-release/build.gradle#565) also shows, how default `proguardArguments` can be supplied.